# TOpenDialog no Lazarus trava ao Executar

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Olá, após a execução do meu aplicativo, quando clico no botão para exibir um OpendDialog no Lazarus IDE o programa simplesmente trava.
Segue o código abaixo:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if open.Execute then
    Showmessage(open.FileName);
end;
```

Após a execução do código acima a tela fica assim:
[OpenDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYav5.png)

Comment: Revise as configurações em Projeto > Opções de Projeto > Depuração e também em Ferramentas > Depurador > "Backend" do depurador.

Comment: Olá @Diego_F já fiz esses procedimentos e nada. Resolvi usar o Embarcadero Delphi Community. Valeu!

Comment: Cuidado ao usar Community para produção! Se a Embarcadero detectar uso indevido eles não tem misericórdia.

Comment: @Diego_F a Embarcadero em sua política de uso diz que eu só passo a pagar licensa se meu faturamento ultrapassar os $5000,00 anuais. Então por enquanto estou tranquilo, pois o projeto é pessoal, não vou comercializa-lo.